# kohana framework, using Security:xss_clean in validation filters

Tags: php, kohana

I have this part of code:

```
    ->filter('username', 'Security::xss_clean')
                ->filter('url', 'Security::xss_clean')
                ->filter('text', 'Security::xss_clean')
```

but it not works and after validation parametres will be inserted via ORM into table columns with html tags.
so, what i do wrong?
or this method works only when writing output data, but not return changed value back to variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which variable are you using for the database input?

If your validation is like this:

```
$validation = Validate::factory ...
```

Then you will need to use:

```
$validation['url'];
```

instead of

```
 $_POST['url'];
```

Comment: Thank you, i thought that validation parametr (f.e. $_POST) automatically commit changes